# Do Gitlab CI/CD resource_groups work across multiple projects?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

Is it possible to block a deployment resource with Gitlab's resource_group feature across multiple projects?
We have a lot of services which should be deployed to the same resource, but want to avoid running all deployment at the same time. Each services has it's own repo.